# Bootstrap: How to deal with iMac vs typical laptop sizes?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive

So I'm currently developing an admin dashboard, my workstation in the office is an iMac (2,500px x 1,5000~ I think) and at home I use a typical laptop with 1366 x 768 resolution.

My problem is that both resolutions fall under the XL category of bootstrap 4 and yet, they display differently. The sidebar in iMac is flawless, but the sidebar in the laptop wraps the buttons in an ugly way. Is there a way to properly address this? Like extend the typical viewport sizes and maybe add an XXL in there?

P.S. I can do some workaround of course, but I'm looking for a better approach to this, not just a temporary fix.

Thanks

Comment: You can always write your own breakpoints and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some media queries in your CSS for big screen sizes:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    body {
        ...
    }
}
```